# Combining "Transform" and FLWOR expressions in Oracle XMLQuery

Tags: sql, oracle11g, xquery, flwor

In the code below i'm trying to insert the "name" element from oldXml2 into oldXml AND update the "test" attribute value in oldXml to "newTest", the resulting combined output is newXml.
The code successfully changes the attribute value but, when I add in the:

```
let $newName := $b/users/user/name
```

clause to get the name element from oldXml2 it stops working.
Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

I'm using Oracle 11g, which uses xquery 1.0.

```
WITH myXml AS (select 1 id, xmltype(
 '<users>
  <user test="oldvalue">
   <userid>id1</userid>
   <name>dave</name>
  </user>
</users>
'
 ) oldXml
 from dual),
myXml2 AS (select 1 id,xmltype(
 '<users>
  <user>
   <userid>id2</userid>
   <name>steve</name>
  </user>
</users>
'
 ) oldXml2
 from dual)
  SELECT oldXml,oldXml2,
XMLQuery(' copy $c := $a
       (: let $newName := $b/users/user/name :)  (: If you add this clause it doesnt work:)
         modify ( rename node $c/users/user/@test as "newTest")
        return $c'
                PASSING a.oldXml as "a" ,b.oldXml2 as "b" RETURNING CONTENT)  newXml
   FROM myXml a
   JOIN myXml2 b
   ON a.id = b.id;
```

The required output in newXml is:

```
<users>
        <user test="newTest">
           <userid>id1</userid>
           <name>dave</name>
        </user>
       <user>
           <userid>id2</userid>
           <name>steve</name>
      </user>
</users>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with oracle's XML approach, but I think there is a `/text()` missing...

Comment: What is the final result you're trying to achieve? You've shown the two input XMLs but not the output XML you want. I'm not sure how you're planning to use newName - change dave to steve (but leave userid alone?), or end up with two name nodes for one user?

Comment: Alex - I've added the required output

Comment: So you want the whole `user` node, not just the name?

Comment: Alex - Yes, I do. My original post was just to show that the "let" expression caused it to fail, but I should have been more clear and put in exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the `let` first and give it its own `return` clause, within which you do the copy/modify:

```
SELECT oldXml, oldXml2,
  XMLQuery('
    let $newName := $b/users/user/name
    return 
      copy $c := $a
      modify (rename node $c/users/user/@test as "newTest")
      return $c'
  PASSING a.oldXml as "a", b.oldXml2 as "b" RETURNING CONTENT) newXml
FROM myXml a
JOIN myXml2 b
ON a.id = b.id;
```

You can then refer to `$newName` within the copy/modify part, but it isn't clear how you want to use it; or why you want that variable instead of referring to `$b/users/user/name` directly, unless your real code will be in a `for` loop.

---

You don't need a `let` to do what you want, you can insert the `$b/users/user` node directly; with an XMLSerialize just to format the output:

```
SELECT oldXml, oldXml2,
  XMLSerialize(CONTENT XMLQuery('
    copy $c := $a
    modify (rename node $c/users/user/@test as "newTest",
      insert nodes $b/users/user after $c/users/user)
    return $c'
  PASSING a.oldXml as "a", b.oldXml2 as "b" RETURNING CONTENT)
  AS VARCHAR2(4000) INDENT SIZE=2) newXml
FROM myXml a
JOIN myXml2 b
ON a.id = b.id;

OLDXML                         OLDXML2                        NEWXML                        
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
<users>                        <users>                        <users>                       
  <user test="oldvalue">         <user>                         <user newTest="oldvalue">   
   <userid>id1</userid>           <userid>id2</userid>            <userid>id1</userid>      
   <name>dave</name>              <name>steve</name>              <name>dave</name>         
  </user>                        </user>                        </user>                     
</users>                       </users>                         <user>                      
                                                                  <userid>id2</userid>      
                                                                  <name>steve</name>        
                                                                </user>                     
                                                              </users>
```

You can use `let` if you add a `return`, as in the first part of the answer, but not sure it gains you anything in this example - maybe it's more useful in your real scenario - making the Xquery:

```
let $newUser := $b/users/user
return
  copy $c := $a
  modify (rename node $c/users/user/@test as "newTest",
    insert nodes $newUser after $c/users/user)
  return $c
```

Comment: Yes, it's useful in the real scenario. One missing "return" keyword and I was stuck. Thanks a lot.